# Swiper Slider - Active Slide is not centered

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

My active slide with my swiperjs slider is not in the center

I did some custom CSS classes to have images vertically aligned and also to have to in correct sizes on mobile screens.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

**Here is the link:**
https://markrabadan.com/personal-work/

Answer (score 2):

1. padding and margin for images messes with sliderjs. Use `spaceBetween: 30` option instead.
2. You can either have clipped images of same size(`image-fit:cover`) or variable size images(`max-width:100%; max-height:100%`).

https://codepen.io/saravanapriyanm/pen/mdLZqOJ?editors=1000

Comment: You mean either use **max-width** or **max-height**. If I use booth, will be distorted on some displays. 

I used your codepen and I adjust the **<main>** height via JS to deal with some issues on mobiles browsers (vh is not considering the address bars ..) 

The div.swiper is inside the **<main>**. So with 
´´´
div.swiper{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}´´´
it should scale to the size of the **<main>**. But on mobile some images are higher then **<main>** 

I can't crop images - it is an artist page and each image should be displayed in the original ratio.

Comment: using max-width & max-height respects image aspect ratio. It's width & height that distorts images.